# Let $I, J$ be ideals in a ring $R$. Prove that the residue class of any element of $I \cap J$ in $R/IJ$ is nilpotent.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $I, J$ be ideals in a ring $R$. Prove that the residue class of any element of $I \cap J$ in $R/IJ$ is nilpotent.

So I know that an element $x$ of a ring is nilpotent if some power of $x$ is 0. I know that $I \cap J$ is an ideal and that $IJ$ is a subset of $I \cap J$. I don't know what a residue of an element of $I \cap J$ in $R/IJ$ means.

So if $x$ is in $I \cap J$, $x \in I$ and $x \in J$. $R/IJ = \{ r + ab : a \in I, b \in J, r \in R\}$

What's next?

Comment: The residue of an element $x \in R$ is the equivalence class $[x] \in R/IJ$.

Comment: Residue means the image of the element under the natural homomorphism $R \to R/IJ$. In this case, $x\in I, x\in J$ and so $x^2\in IJ$

Comment: Hint: $[x]^n = [x^n] \in R/IJ$ is zero if and only if $x^n \in IJ$.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan Hi: please consider crafting that into an answer since it is basically an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Residue means the image of the element under the natural homomorphism $R \to R/IJ$. In this case, $x\in I\cap J \Rightarrow x \in I$ and $x\in J$, and so $x^2 \in IJ$. Thus
$$
[x]^2 = [x^2] = [0] \text{ in } R/IJ
$$